# What are the best suggestions for cutting gloves

Tags: equipment, knives

I've never used a cut proof or cut resistant glove but I think it may come in handy when using a mandolin slicer or prepping a bunch veggies.  Any suggestions on the pros and cons between cut resistant and cut proof gloves?  Any specific products you would suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "cut proof", so you should still try to be careful. I use a [Microplane glove](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001QXZORE) with my mandolin, and it's worked out quite well so far. Cook's Illustrated also recommends this glove.

Comment: I've seen real cut proof gloves (at least, for most reasonable cutting), but they ruin your blades -- they're [chain mail, made from stainless steel](http://www.cooking.com/products/shprodde.asp?SKU=162133).  Plate mail doesn't work, as it tends to be outside the hand, mounted on leather, so doesn't really help in cooking.

Comment: @Joe Those definitely look heavy duty . . . but you could still probably put a hole in one if you were really reckless (or motivated). I just wanted to make sure nobody tried putting their glove to a test.

Comment: I have a glove that I made years ago from I think it was 18ga galvanized tie wire, so it's heavier (and larger gaps, as the rings are larger) ... I'd say it'd stop most any slicing from a knife ... really thin piercing (ice pick) or heavy chopping (meat cleaver, machette) might get through, but against standard kitchen tasks, you'll be safe.  Maybe we could get mythbusters to test 'em?  (some hot dogs for fingers, and see what it'd take to get through)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem years ago, I am a clumsy person and always cut my self whenever I work or cook in the kitchen. I avoided using knives for many year and just throw almost everything to the food processor. But everything changed when my friend send me this NoCry [Cut Resistant Gloves last Christmas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IVM1TKO), and boy..everything changed after that. I am more confident in handling knives, specially when slicing meat. Hope this help. :)

Comment: As of August17, 2014 Amazon says this is out of stock and they don't know when it might be available.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I did check couple of days ago and now this is available.http://www.amazon.com/NoCry-Comfortable-Performance-Environments-Small-Medium/dp/B00IVM1TKO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1409659861&sr=8-2&keywords=cut+resistant+gloves